# JavaFX use superclass in EventHandler

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx, extends, super

I have multiple controller-classes, which extend another controller. When I create an EventHandler in an extending controller-class, I can't use "super.something". It works in a normal method, but not in an EventHandler. Is there any other option?

Here is a little example excerpt:

```
public class ViewController {

    @FXML
    private TextField idField;

    public TextField getIdField() {
        return idField;
    }
}
```

-

```
public class ExtendingViewController extends ViewController {

    @FXML
    private Label testLabel;

    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> createBtnHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

               //This does not work. "super" does not seem to exist in this method.
               testLabel.setText(super.getIdField());

            }
        };
    }

    public void testMethod(){
        //this does work
        testLabel.setText(super.getIdField());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work without the `super.` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `super` here. If you leave out the `super.`, the java compiler checks the anonymus class for a `getIdField` method and since it does not find one, it checks the containing class for this method. (Using `super` or `this` in `testMethod` does not change the result, since `getIdField` is not overwritten in `ExtendingViewController`.)

```
testLabel.setText(getIdField().getText());
```

You can however access members of the superclass of the containing class using `ContainingClass.super`:

```
private EventHandler<ActionEvent> createBtnHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        testLabel.setText(ExtendingViewController.super.getIdField().getText());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because super is a relative reference. 
When referencing super from `testMethod` super is the `ViewController`, but when referencing super from `createBtnHandler` super is the `EventHandler` super class.
(Event handler inherits from object so object would be the super) 
See - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html

To make this work you could make a class that inherits `EventHander` and pass a reference to the method you would like to invoke.

```
public class CustomEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    private IEventsHandler mEventsHandler;

    public CustomEventHandler(IEventsHandler eventsHandler)
    {
        mEventsHandler = eventsHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        mEventsHandler.testMethod();
    }
}

public interface IEventsHandler {
    void testMethod();
}


public class ExtendingViewController extends ViewController implements IEventsHandler  {

    @FXML
    private Label testLabel;

    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> createBtnHandler = new CustomEventHandler(this);

    public void testMethod(){
        testLabel.setText(super.getIdField());
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the `EventHandler` used in this question is not this one, but the [one from javafx](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html).